# How to import Google Font with same font-weight

Tags: fonts, local, google-fonts

I want to import the *Poppins Google Font* in my website to use internal font and to use the option *font-display: swap;* (for best *PageSpeed* score).

Actually I'm using this code into *css*:

`@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700");`

This contains all *font-weight*.. To import all fonts weight I need to download and upload all *woff2* manually?

Comment: ...What? The import you show will download the stylesheet and associated fonts assets from google when CSS gets loaded. Which is almost guaranteed to be faster than have users first download it from your own server, and _then **redownload**_ it from google. Almost every person on the planet is closer to a Google data center endpoint than they will be to your website's server. The only speedup would be if you could convince people to _install_ the font locally, which you should never, ever, do, because CSS `local()` does not verify versions in any way whatsoever.

Comment: No.. I want to load in my server the fonts, because now my server is loading the fonts from Google and this don't have font-display: swap.. Required by PageSpeed Insight

Comment: It's not required at all, but if you absolutely feel you need it: you have the URL right there so just extend the CSS in it. Open https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700 in a tab, copy-paste the code and add your font-display rules, then save that as `whatever.css` and point your `<link>` to that `whatever.css` instead of the fonts.googleapis url.

Comment: Perfect.. Thank you! :-)